# Including SQL for hibernate exception in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is there anyway I can include the SQL for a hibernate exception in Grails?
I know I can use SQL logging and then cross correlate threads, request id etc, but it would be nice if there was some configuration I could use for this.

So if hibernate throws a StaleStateException, I can see the SQL it was trying to execute at that time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grails does not provide anything specific to help with this and as far as I know there is nothing in Hibernate to directly correlate an exception with the SQL which relates to the cause of the exception.